# how to run/execute a java code(maven project) outside the IDE

Tags: java, maven, jenkins-pipeline, execution

I am new to programming, there is a maven project with java code that does certain testing and it runs regularly through Jenkins pipeline, it runs the tests on an environment (linux machine).
Now what I am struggling and not knowing where to start is how can I test this code manually knowing that it has different Mains (i.e Main1 , Main2 , Main3) and I want to run a certain Main not all, for example only Main1 which tests specific thing.
ps: I have the code in Intellij, but I want to run it outside intellij, I want to run it on the environment I'm testing (linux maachine).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first you have to `build` the maven project using this command in your project directory:

```
mvn package
```

After a successful build, you will see a `.jar` file has created in target folder same as your package name and version.

finally you have to RUN the project.

To run the project use this command:

```
java -cp target/jarfileName.jar path_of_the_project_startup
```

Done.

Comment: aha great, and if I want to debug the code? for example now I am getting an error but the code I am running is on a linux machine not on the intellij, so is that possible?
Or I should everytime I do a change and then build and then run the jar file on the linux machine? that will be a hard work and not convenient.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to build your maven project. Navigate to the project folder (you must have the project root pom.xml there) open a terminal and to build it type:

```
mvn clean package
```

Depending on your project structure, a successful run of this command will result in several target folders at different levels for your modules and possibly .jar files inside them. Navigate into the target folder of the module in which your entry point (main) is and check jar file name. Let's call it jarname.jar for simplicity.

In case you have several entry points in the same jarname.jar, you can run them like this:

```
java -cp jarname.jar Main1
java -cp jarname.jar Main2
java -cp jarname.jar Main3
```

If you want to run from terminal and still debug from IntelliJ, run app with:

```
-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005
```

and then create a 'Remote JVM Debug' config in IntelliJ on same port (5005), adding some break points and 'Debug'.

As an alternative, you can create Run Config 'Java Scratch' from IntelliJ to run/debug your app.

Comment: so the final command on the terminal will look like that:

```java -cp jarname.jar Main1 -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005``` ? 


and on Intellij I create Remote JVM Debug and set the port 5005?

Comment: Yes. You can use suspend=y if you need to debug some initialisation code of the application (the virtual machine would be suspended before it had the opportunity to load the main class, and the attached debugger would resume the execution of the VM).